# Routing url such as www.mydomain.com/username in blazor web assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, controller, blazor-webassembly

I would like my blazor webassembly application to be able to route the following URLs:

[www.mydomain.com/{username}](http://www.mydomain.com/%7Busername%7D)

Based on the username this will load up the person information

This is similar to what linktree does

I am not sure on how to do this please point me to the right direction

I have to change the controller but its expecting me to have a full parameter call e.g mydomain.com/?id=username

And I want it to be mydomain.com/username

Answer (score 0):

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#route-parameters) related,try as below in Blazor WASM razor compnent:

```
@page "/currentroute/{username}"
```

in code block :

```
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? username { get; set; }
    ......
}
```

Result:

[image]